# Cannot Git Blame files

Tags: xcode, git, git-blame

I use Xcode and this repo on two separate laptops.  On one laptop, in Xcode I can select the version editor pane and it shows me blame information on each line such as who made the commit and when.  However, on the other laptop I always get the error `could not blame {file}. Error: fatal: no such ref: HEAD`.

I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it.  As I pull often, the repo's should be both very similar (barring gitignore differences or something). So I'm not sure whether or not there is a minor different in the .git folder on one laptop.  I know HEAD is a reference to a certain commit but beyond that I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: `HEAD` is, in fact, not just *a* commit, it's *the* commit: the current commit. There must always be a current commit, with one special exception: an empty repository or orphan branch has no current commit. Orphan branches are rare (require using `git checkout --orphan`) and presumably you would know if this were an empty repository, so perhaps this is some Xcode bug.

Comment: i'm not using an orphan branch,  like i say if i checkout the same branch on both laptops after a fresh pull, one Xcode shows blames while the other presents this error.

Answer (score 0):

"could not blame": Please turn off the "Blame" editor. Look like you added a new file, which is not yet committed. So Blame editor have no data to show and it throws error as "Could not blame"

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a second `.git` folder somewhere in your repo subfolders (at least that was what cause for me). Xcode does not support this.

To fix this, go to your repo root:

```
cd ~/Development/repo
```

Search the subfolders for stray repos:

```
find . -name ".git"
```

If there's anything other than `./.git` in the output, remove it:

```
rm -rf subfolder/some_folder/.git
```

If you had Xcode running at this point, restart it and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Steps to fix not working blame for line in Xcode: -
1. Go to the project directory first.
2. Fist remove all the git process 
   use this command to find all git process `find . -name ".git"`
3. If there's anything other than ./.git in the output, remove it:
   use this command to remove `rm -rf subfolder/some_folder/.git` 
4. After that, you can delete your project folder and clone the same repo from 
   stash
   use git clone "ssh key for your repo"
5. After cloning the project, an open project you will able to see blame for a 
   line.

In my case this steps resolved the problem, I am not sure that will work for all but at least try it once.
```